# $\int_{3}^{ab+2}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{3}^{a+2}f\left(x\right)dx+\int_{3}^{b+2}f\left(x\right)dx$ where $a,b\in \left(1,\infty \right)$ find $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

> $f(x)$ is a differentiable function defined for x>2 satisfying $$\int_{3}^{ab+2}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{3}^{a+2}f\left(x\right)dx+\int_{3}^{b+2}f\left(x\right)dx$$ where $a,b\in \left(1,\infty \right)$ and find $f(x)$

I found this question on an Australian math exam and it was actually a mulitple choice question where the intended method was trial and error.

I was wondering if there was any more intuitive approach to the question.

[The question can be accessed here with the MCQ options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyXVb.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE.  It seems to be a typo in your question. It is $$\int_{3}^{ab+2}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{3}^{a+2}f\left(x\right)dx+\int_{3}^{b+2}f\left(x\right)dx$$

Comment: Oh apologies! Thank you for picking up on that :))

Comment: Differentiate to get a functional equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> f(x) is a differentiable function defined for x>2 satisfying $$\int_{3}^{ab+2}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{3}^{a+2}f\left(x\right)dx+\int_{3}^{b+2}f\left(x\right)dx$$ where $a,b\in \left(1,\infty \right)$ find $f(x)$

Take derivative to $a$

$$bf(ab+2)=f(a+2)$$

Let $a=1$

$$f(b+2)=\frac{f(3)}{b}$$

Let $x=b+2$

$$f(x)=\frac{f(3)}{x-2}$$

where $f(3)$ is some constant $c=f(3)$, then we have

$$f(x)=\frac{c}{x-2}$$

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your explanation! I'm a bit confused at the part 'take derivative to a'?

I'm really sorry for being potentially annoying  

Comment: right, by fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Yep, but I don't get how that yielded to $bf\left(ab+2\right)=f\left(a+2\right)$ and how you could let $a=1$.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the derivative $\frac{d}{dt} \int_1^{2t} f(x)dx$ ?

Comment: $2f(2t)$? 

Oh so essentially what you did was $$\frac{d}{da}\int _3^{ab+2}\:f\left(x\right)dx=bf\left(ab+2\right)$$ $$\frac{d}{da}\int _3^{a+2}\:f\left(x\right)dx=f\left(a+2\right)$$ $$\frac{d}{da}\int _3^{b+2}\:f\left(x\right)dx=0$$

How are you allowed to do that? It seems like you turned a function of $x$ into a function of what was meant to be a constant.

Comment: No, the integral is not a constant, since it depends on $a$ or $b$, and they can vary.

Comment: If you want to do it a bit more explicitly, you can set $F(x)$ to be an antiderivative of $f(x)$, i.e. $F'(x) = f(x)$, then the FTOC turns the integral equation into $F(ab+2) - F(3) = F(a+2) - F(3) + F(b+2) - F(3)$, then you can simplify that and differentiate it with respect to $a$ while keeping $b$ constant.

Comment: Oh that clarifies a lot, thank you guys.

Comment: Hey, @ConMan, is there a specific name for this approach? I think its a cool way of going about this problem and I'm interested in learning more about it.

Comment: I'd suggest looking up the Leibniz integral formula, aka "differentiating under the integral sign".